# How Can I Remove Newline and Add All Words To a List

Tags: python, row, newline

I have a txt file it contains 4 lines. (like a poem)
The thing that I want is to add all words to one list.
For example the poem like this :

> I am done with you,
>
> Don't love me anymore

I want it like this : ['I', 'am', 'done', 'with', 'you', 'dont', 'love', 'me', 'anymore']

But I can not remove the row end of the first sentence it gives me 2 separated list.

```
romeo = open(r'd:\romeo.txt')
list = []

for line in romeo:
    line = line.rstrip()
    line = line.split()
    list = list + [line]
print(list)
```

Comment: ```your_string.replace("\n", "")``` this will remove new lines.

Comment: does not works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open(r'd:\romeo.txt', 'r') as msg:
    data = msg.read().replace("\n"," ")

data = [x for x in data.split() if x.strip()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter:

```
with open(r'd:\romeo.txt', 'r') as msg:
   list = " ".join(msg.split()).split(' ')
```

Or with removing the comma:

```
with open(r'd:\romeo.txt', 'r') as msg:
   list = " ".join(msg.replace(',', ' ').split()).split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [regular expresion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) like this.

```
import re
poem = '' # your poem
split = re.split(r'\040|\n', poem)
print(split)
```

Regular expresion `\040` is for white space an `\n` to match a new line.

The output is:

```
['I', 'am', 'done', 'with', 'you,', "Don't", 'love', 'me', 'anymore']
```